# ZK Fingerprint Template to be save to table TEMPLATE in SQL Server database (C#)

Tags: sql-server, templates, fingerprint, zkteco, zkemkeeper

My project is to get FP template from ZKFingerprint device and store into a SQL Server database. Using `ZKEMKEEPER.dll`, I manage to use the function to get and display FP template by use function below :

```
GetUserTmpExStr(iMachineNumber, sdwEnrollNumber, idwFingerIndex, out iFlag, out sTmpData, out iTmpLength)
```

Output:

```
SuVTUzIxAAADpqkECAUHCc7QAAAbp2kBAAAAg0sdxKY5AJEPcwCQAHSp7QBZABgPrABYpvsPfgB0ALoP0KZ4AJUPdABHAACo7wCEAB0PjQCJpmkPeQCPALMOaKaVAPcO1gBcAJqpqADGAJAPUADX...
```

The problem is I can't save the template to database, because the datatype in the table for template column is `Image`. Below is the sample template value in database :

```
0x4D8353533231000004C0C70408050709CED000001CC16901000000846D2E85C......
```

Can someone help :

- Identify what type of numeral of that template value in database, so I can convert the template output from device, and successfully save to database.
- Or any other function can be use? Need you guys expertise

Please I just need to store get fp template to the database, I am sure someone here are very expert and knowledgeable.

Comment: `image` data type will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using this data type in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use it. Use `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Template is a base64 format data of a encrypted string. So, you can very well use the String column to store the template.